# Google App Engine and PHP Testing Upload to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm currently working on a file upload section of a project in `PHP` and I'm looking to upload data to a bucket. I know how to do this just fine, but I'm wondering what the best way to test it is. Is there anyway to test it locally or do I have to deploy and test every time?

Answer (score 1):

There is a complete simulation in the dev appserver, including uploading, reading and writing to a cloud storage bucket - you don't need to upload to production to test/debug it.

Comment: Do the files actually go the the Cloud Storage Bucket?

Comment: Not when using the development server.

Comment: So how would I know if the code I've written would upload properly?

Comment: That's the point of the development environment - allow you to test that the code is correct and working without having to use the real services.